# What is the gt for here? "if [ $VARIABLE -gt 0 ]; then"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What does the `-gt` mean here:

`if [ $CATEGORIZE -gt 0 ]; then`

This is part of a bash script I'm working with.

Also, where can I find a list of "flags" that go in there so I can have for reference in the future?

Comment: `man bash`, search for `-gt`.

Comment: -gt is for greater than comparison using which you can compare one variable which is greater than your expected value or not. Like $VAR -gt 10 means value of VAR is greater than 10 or not. So its used for comparison purpose. You can also use -lt (less than), -le (less than or equal to), -ge (greater than or equal to), -eq (equal to) keyword also in Linux shell script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-gt` is an arithmetic test that denotes *greater than*.

Your condition checks if the variable `CATEGORIZE` is greater than zero.

Quoting from `help test` (the `[` is a command known as `test`; `help` is a shell builtin that provides help on shell builtins):

```
  arg1 OP arg2   Arithmetic tests.  OP is one of -eq, -ne,
                 -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.
```

- `-eq`: Equal
- `-ne`: Not equal
- `-lt`: Less than
- `-le`: Less than or equal to
- `-gt`: Greater than
- `-ge`: Greater than or equal to

You could also express the condition in an *arithmetic context*<sup>1</sup> by saying:

```
if ((CATEGORIZE > 0)); then
```

instead of

```
if [ $CATEGORIZE -gt 0 ]; then
```

<sup>1</sup> Quoting from `help '(('`:

> `(( ... )): (( expression ))`
>
> ```
> Evaluate arithmetic expression.
>
> The EXPRESSION is evaluated according to the rules for arithmetic
> evaluation.  Equivalent to "let EXPRESSION".
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns 1 if EXPRESSION evaluates to 0; returns 0 otherwise.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

`-gt` means "greater than", compared arithmetically

`[` is (peculiarly) an alias of `test` (with a mandatory last argument of `]`, to make it look like a pair of brackets).

`bash` has its own "builtin" version of `[`/`test`, so any bash reference (e.g `man bash`, `info bash`, or http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) will document that, or `man [`/`man test` should give you the documentation for the standard standalone version.

Specifically, [this page gives an overview of the command, as implemented by bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-test), and [this page lists the available operators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions).

As well as arithmetic and string tests, you may come across the `-e` test, for "file exists", as in `[ -e /hard/coded/path/$variable_filename ]`

bash also includes a slightly extended version, [in the form of `[[ ... ]]`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b).